# AngularJS - Run $http.get without $apply

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use angular $http.get to fetch changes from API and I can't figure out how to do this without being forced to apply after every GET request. Running $scope.$apply() only when needed would be optimal. If we have stuff to do then apply. Otherwise no apply. Is this possible?

Using my code below apply is ran after every get request:

```
$interval(function () {
    $http.get('http://myangularapp.com/stuffToDo').
        success(function (data) {
            if(data.stuffToDo) {
                $scope.doStuff();
                // Apply needed
            }
            // If we have no stuff to do don't apply
        }
        ).
        error(function () {
            // handle error
        });
}, 5000, 0, false);
```

Comment: Question is not much clear to me,  you can `$scope.apply()` in your `IF` condition.

Comment: You're not supposed to use `$scope.$apply()` for all modifications, only when a third party lib (or your own code) changes the DOM. In a nutshell `$scope.$apply()` is used to tell angularjs that your DOM tree has modifications and it should update it.

Comment: I know, but I'd like to avoid unnecessary diggest cycle here. Like you can do with interval. The last false argument tells that no apply is needed at the end of interval. I'd like to do the same for the success function of the get request and run it manually when needed.